# Save new data - React Native + Firebase

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

can any of you guys give me an example of update in user/uid? How can I give an update?

I know I can do this to give an update: `` database().ref(`/users/${uid}`).update(newData) ``, but where do I implement this code?

Comment: You can do that "anywhere" - depends on your architecture as to where makes the most sense. If you're using redux, then that should be an action exposed as something like `updateUser`. If you're not using it, then it should be some form of onChange or method your component has that will invoke the Firebase call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you use Redux, use this query in your actions page.**

for ex:

```js
    In src/actions/userActions.js
    
import firebase from '../your/path/";
rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
        
export const updateUser = (newData)=> ((dispatch, getState)=> {

      // get the uid of the user here, you can get it directly from state if you stored it in state earlier, or you can use, the currentUser method from firebase if you used their auth module as well.
    
const state = getState();
let uid = state.uid;
rootRef.child(`/users/${uid}`).update(newData);
    
// dispatch something
     
);
```

**If you don't use Redux,
just wrap the update operation in a function in your component page and call it when required**

for ex:

In src/components/UserUpdate.js

```js
// import necessary react and react native modules
import firebase from '../your/path/of/firebase config'
rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

export default class UserUpdate extends Component {
  updateUser = () => {
    // get your userId and new data ;
    rootRef.child(`users/${uid}`).update(newData);
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      TouchableOpacity onPress = {
        this.updateUser()
      } >
      <
      Text > Update User < /Text> <
      /TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

NOTE:

1. newData must be an object (JSON format)
2. all the queries return promise, so handle them properly using then and catch
3. the way I create actions might be a bit different from yours as I don't use switch cases, but I use a helper function to generate them for me.

Comment: I'm doing: savename() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });
    update() {
      database().ref(`/users/${uid}`).update(newData);
    }.catch((error) => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      });
      alert("ERROR!")
    });
  }
------------------------------------
onPress={this.savename.bind()}

Comment: what are you using savename for? is it just to set loading as true?

Here is my understanding, when you call the update function, the state of loading has to be set to true and then after request, set to false

Code
 update = ()=> {
     this.setState({loading: true});
     firebase.database().ref(`/users/${uid}`).update(newData).then(()=> {
         this.setState({loading: false});
     }).catch((err)=> {
         this.setState({loading: false}); // to make sure, loader stops if an error occurs
         console.log("Error ",err);
     });
     
 }
 onPress = {this.update}

Comment: I did it the way you told me, but when I click on 'SAVE' I'm getting an error: 'Can not find variable: uid'. Do you think I need to import something?

Comment: No, you aren't sending any uid to the function, uid is just a variable, it's not keyword, pass it as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I can solve this error? I placed the project in GitHub: https://github.com/JVRodrigues256/firebase_reactnative_project/blob/master/screens/forms/username.js